# how to use termux commands between python script

Tags: python, termux

i have written a python script which takes a multi line input from user and displays multi line output.

i generally paste the input when i use pydroid3 and copy the output

i recently installed termux and i am looking towards automating my script like when i execute this

`$ python script.py` command, the input should be automatically drawn from clipboard using `termux-clipboard-get` and the final output from my python script should be copied to clipboard using `termux-clipboard-set`

Answer (score 0):

you should use the os module.

```
import os
os.system('termux-clipboard-get')
os.system('termux-clipboard-set')
```

considering the `termux-clipboard-set` and `termux-clipboard-get` are shell/linux commands